# Problema al superponer imgData (javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas

me estreno en este foro jaja, el caso es que queria tener un pequeño programa que me permitiera manipular los pixeles y funciona, pero tengo conflictos con el canal alfa, pues al usar 2 imagedata superpuestos, esperaba que el canal alfa de ambos funcionaran entre si, pero el problema es que la segunda imagen me sobreeescribe por completo la segunda. 
En el ejemplo que dejo, yo esperaria que se visualice aproximadamente el rectangulo rojo, pero aun no lo consigo.

```
function testrectangle()
{
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);



    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 25;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

1. `var c` y `var ctx` son constantes. Las declaras una sola vez y fuera de la función `testrectangle`.
2. en la primera parte de tu función recuperas la información de cada pixel del canvas y le das un color rojo. Finalmente reemplazas cada pixel del canvas con el nuevo pixel rojo.

```js
    //recuperas la información de cada pixel del canvas
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
    var i;
    //y le das un color rojo
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

3. en la segunda parte de tu función recuperas la información de cada pixel del canvas y le cambias el color a verde transparente. Después vuelves a reemplazar cada pixel del canvas con el nuevo pixel verde transparente que le corresponde.  O sea los que eran rojos ahora son verdes.

```js
    // la variable imgData ya está declarada, no necesitas declararla otra vez
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
    // tampoco necesitas volver a declarar la variable i//var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 25;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0);
```

Espero que esto sea lo que preguntabas.

Comment: Gracias, aun no se usar bien el foro :c jaja, podrias reconfirmarme la respuesta con lo nuevo que añadi, por favor

Comment: dos cosas: 1. Para añadir información editas la pregunta, no pones esta información en una respuesta. 2. Para lo que tu necesitas dibujas dos rectángulos utilizando fillRect()

Comment: Ok, pero queria usar la matriz para usar muchas mas funcionalidades a futuro, no solo para crear un rectangulo solido de un color

Comment: Utilizar imageData puede ser muy interesante pero sale bastante caro de punto de vista del rendimiento.  Siempre que puedas utilizar otra cosa no lo dudes.

Comment: Si, tienes razon, pero deseo aprender a usarlo, pues es la unica alternativa que he observado para manejar los colores de los pixeles y tambien para el tratamiento de algoritmos mas complicados que quiero aprender a usar en un futuro

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por responder, pero lo que pretendia es que abajo se dibujara el cuadrado rojo y encima pintar otro cuadrado en la misma posicion pero NO SOBREESCRIBIENDOLO sino que se mezclen los colores segun su canal alfa. Algo asi
[image: Superposicion de colores segun su canal alfa]
O No se si sea necesario recurrir a los algoritmos que producen ese efecto, espero que no jaja